# Maintaining SpatialPolygonDataFrame Column when using extract function to extract pixel values from a Raster in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, classification, extract, raster

My goal is to perform a random-forest classification for multispectral, high-resolution UAV imagery.

Currently I am preparing training data for the algorithm. I started writing a for-loop to extract the pixel values of my raster (RasterBrick) using the training area polygons (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). However, a colleague pointed me to Rs extract function which is probably easier and looks far less cluttered.

```
###Rast1B is a RasterBrick and contains pixel value info on 4 Bands (B1-B4)
> print(Rast1B)
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 10000, 10000, 1e+08, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 361000, 362000, 5619000, 5620000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/foofoo
names      :  B1,  B2,  B3,  B4 
min values :   0,   0,   0,   0 
max values : 255, 255, 255, 255 

###Shape1B is a SpatialPolygonDataframes and contains ROI polygons as well as a class id column (1 or 2, there are only two classes)
> print(Shape1B)
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 104 
extent      : 361420.1, 361607.7, 5619007, 5619334  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : id 
min values  :  1 
max values  :  2
```

Extraction returns a DF with 5 columns. The class id column from the SpatialPolygonsDF is lost and replaced by the polygon ids, though.

```
trainingDF <- extract(Rast1B, Shape1B, df=TRUE)
    ###Just the first three rows to give an overview
    > print(bar2)
        ID  B1  B2  B3  B4
    1    1 105 123 145 116
    2    1 112 131 154 123
    3    1 116 135 153 126
```

I'm looking for a way to use extract while maintaining the class id for each pixel as this is required for the creation of training and testing data. Its probably also possible to add the column manually after extraction based on the polygon ids but I'm unsure how to approach this since I'm very new to R.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`ID` refers to the (order of the) polygons; so you can use an attribute of those polygons, in your case the field `id`, to make the connection. The following should do it

```
trainingDF <- data.frame(trainingDF)
trainingDF$id <-  Shape1B$id[trainingDF$ID]
```

Comment: I can't upvote since I'm a new user but thank you very much. Connecting via id worked for me and looks much cleaner than my for-loop.